# Minecraft Plugin Build Number

Tags: mysql, maven, plugins, minecraft

I'm currently making a minecraft plugin, and I want the version to increase when ever I build the jar file. I'm using maven too. Any ideas? Should I use MySQL or maven build number? I'm also using intellj idea to code my plugins.

Edit 1: Could I maybe store a value in the jar and every time I start the plugin, it will increase it by one. And the value won't be reset/change every time I stop server

Comment: Why not use SNAPSHOT versions for testing and the Maven release plugin when you release?

Comment: I want really want this because I want to prevent the I didn't upload the wrong version. As I'm hosting the server in a panel. I sometimes didn't wait for the upload to finish and start the server. So it will start an old version of the plugin. I just want to confirm that I'm really enabling the newest version plugin.

Comment: What mod framework are you using? Bukkit, Forge, what?

Comment: @Draco18s As he said "plugin" my guess goes to bukkit

Comment: @Draco18s I'm using Spigot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, link if someone wants for reference, https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/maven-build-number.319030/